# Coinbase FIX API - rate limit algorithm

Tags: coinbase-api

According to the Coinbase [documentation](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/docs/fix-rate-limits), the FIX Order Entry API rate limits are:

- 50 requests per rolling second per session
- 100 messages per second
  in bursts

How do we have to understand the second limitation ? What are exactly bursts / How do we know that we are in bursts ?